# How many colors needed for the entire graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

If a graph is disconnected and you know that the minimal color required for each component is x, how do you find the minimum color required for the entire graph?

Would it just be x?

Comment: If you colored each graph with $x$ colors, would you have a proper coloring?

Comment: it's not specified so I think I'm assuming it does not having proper coloring.

Comment: I guess I should have been more exact. If you color each connected component properly with $x$ colors (which you can do by assumption), do you have a proper coloring of the entire graph?

Comment: then yes it does

Comment: Then $x\geq \chi(G)$, as we can properly color it with $x$ colors. Can you argue the other inequality that $x\leq \chi(G)$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if a graph $G$ has connected components $G_1, \ldots, G_r$, then the chromatic number $\chi(G)$ of $G$ is the maximum of $\chi(G_1),\ldots,\chi(G_r)$. So, if $\chi(G_i)=x$ for all $i$, then $\chi(G)=x$.